# MYSQL Joins to retrieve result

Tags: php, mysql

I will try to be as explanatory as possible regarding my question. I am using MYSQL/PHP to fetch data from two tables with the structure looking like the following:

```
     table A 
+---------+------------+
| userid  | username   |
+---------+------------+
|    1    |     john   |
|    2    |     doe    |
|    3    |     lewis  |
+---------+------------+

     table B
+---------+------------+-----------+
| id      |from_userid | to_userid |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|    1    |     1      |     3     |
|    2    |     3      |     2     |
|    3    |     1      |     2     |
|    4    |     2      |     1     |
+---------+------------+-----------+

Am trying to achieve the following:

+---------+------------+----------------------+
| id      |sender username| receiver username |
+---------+------------+----------------------+
|    1    |  john         |     lewis         |
|    2    |  lewis        |     doe           |
|    3    |  john         |     doe           |
|    4    |  doe          |     john          |
+---------+------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see, instead of returning the sender or receiver user id, I am returning their username according to Table A.

can I use left or right joins in this scenario? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT b.id, sender.username AS sender_username, receiver.username AS receiver_username
FROM tableB AS b
  JOIN tableA AS sender ON b.from_userid = sender.userid
  JOIN tableA AS receiver ON b.to_userid = receiver.userid
```

Comment: I didn't test this, but it should work. It uses `INNER JOIN`s, I assumed there is always a "from" and "to", and those records always exist in `tableA`.

Comment: "from" and "to" do not exist in table A. Table B get the values of "from_userid and to_userid" upon a form submission. The field contained in table A are strictly userid and username. Do you suspect wrong database design here?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. This query gets only the username from table A. Look at the `ON` clauses, the first one says that the `from_userid` field from table B should match the `userid` field from the `sender` table (i.e. table A). The second one is similar. The DB design looks fine to me

Comment: I tried the above query and it's returning the value for userid and not username based on table A

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins would work fine, you just need to do two of them...
Left and right joins are only needed when you want to get all records from one table and some from another table.  In this case you have two distinct relationships thus the need for two joins. My MySQL skills are a bit rusty so I don't know if ' or [ are used as separators on the table/field names with spaces.

```
Select t1.ID, T1.userName as 'Sender userName',  T2.username as 'Receiver username'
FROM [Table A] A
INNER JOIN [Table B] T1 
  on T1.from_userid = A.userID
INNER JOIN [Table B] T2 
  on T2.to_userid = A.userID
```